Install Frigidair oven Model No FCF13083ASA (Fan oven plus induction hob) in Australia 240v LNE system
The oven is American and is 3 wire.  I have looked in the oven and it has 3 x  120VAC  motors, (lock,main fan, cooling fan).  Cooling fan looks like shaded pole and has 3 wires (neutral plus 2).
The control board is an Electrolux Home Products P/N A171068803 and appears to switch one leg to these motors, the other leg is connected to the white(E/N)
I have no schematics, so am guessing a lot.
I could interface the 120VAC devices with small transformers, the 3 wire motor is an issue.
Does anyone have any schematics or advise that may assist

Is there a reason you're attached to this oven in particular instead of something made for the AU/NZ market?

Yes we like the functions and quality

By three wire(/3) do you mean two hots, a neutral and the usually unmentioned ground, or just two hots and neutral?  Is the cooling fan two speed?  Maybe the reason for an extra wire.
